# Issue with hosting subsite in IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, deployment, iis-8

Query regarding the configuration of website in IIS (Version-10.0.1741), we have configured a mainsite with name - Mainsite and subsite with name - Subsite. Both these sites have been mapped to two different physical paths with different content in index.html files only. Inside the server, basic settings of the mainsite is mapped to localhost and port 80. But when we try to browse the subsite http://localhost/Subsite/ it is always rendering the content of the mainsite and not the content of the subsite.
But we have tried everything in another server IIS, the same configuration is working fine. Mainsite and subsite content are loading fine.
Can someone suggest any part which must be checked or configured in our IIS for this issue. Thanks in advance.

Note:
We have tried adding virtual directory and converting that to website, but still it is not working
Also we have checked the permissions of the directory we have permissions to the physical path as well
We have tried URL rewrite from subsite to another mainsite called secondsubsite as well but then it is not working
We have checked the IIS event viewer logs and also checked the logs under IIS logging section still we haven't got any error logs

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis IIS never has the concept of "subsite". If you want to host something as an application under a site, you have to consult its vendor (or developers) to see what's required. Many developers today assume an isolated deployment as a site (with exclusive routing rules), so they don't support deployment as applications under sites.

Comment: Hi, We have just named it as a subsite but still we have only one index.html inside the application called subsite under the site name mainsite. but we have configured the same thing one of our other server where content from mainsite and subsite is loading as expected. Only in this server when i browse subsite it is always showing the content of mainsite. Also we have enabled directory browsing and checked still no luck. Also we have checked the IIS logs and no clue from that as well.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.